# Forced to update Wordpress database after CSV import

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce, csv-import

Each time i try to import products into my Wordpress/Woocommerce store using the CSV Import Suite plugin, I get a message saying "Database Update Required". Even after an update and another import attempt 30 seconds later, It requires an Update again. After each database update it 'destroys' my database by setting all the tables to their defaults settings (So I lose widgets/content/pages... everything). Luckily I have backups.

- The csv file i'm importing works fine on other Wordpress installs.
- I've tried it with a variety of themes.
- I've disable all other plugins.
- The database appears to have write access (since I can manipulate it
  through the WP-Admin and manually through phpMyAdmin)
- I tried setting the db_upgraded field to 0 (Under the wp_options
  table)

**How can I fix this and just start importing products?** Thanks!

PHP version 5.4 |
Wordpress 3.9 |
Woocommerce 2.1.7 |
CSV Import Suite 1.9.4 |
MySQL 5.37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same error on another site with the same plugin. so I ditched that plugin for the "Woocommerce CSV Import" By Allaerd Mensonides and that seems to be working well.